# Launch app with custom URI - gmail removing links

Tags: android, hyperlink, gmail, uri

I'm trying to build a custom URI scheme so that when a user clicks on it, my application will be launched and read any parameters needed from that link.

This is working fine on iOS, since the native email client keeps the links there, but on Android I'm having some troubles.

If I send an email containing a link, like `MyCustomURI://test`, the link will be removed. This happens on gmail web client and also on gmail native android application.

I'd like the users to open the application from the email, without going to any intermediate server, so performing an http request is not an option.

Please let me know if there is any way to achieve this.

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use "http" as scheme, so the link will not be removed. But the drawback is it will prompt you for your app or browser. You may also add a host, and path or pathPrefix if needed.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <data android:scheme="http" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```